# More than one @EnableJpaRepositories in java?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

`Hello, i have to add native queries in different .xml files, in my src/main/resources i have two files:

```
queries.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <!-- Define un SQL Query nativo -->
    <sql-query name="test2">
        <![CDATA[
            SELECT 1+1 AS TEST1,
                   2+2 AS TEST2,
                   'test' AS test
        ]]>
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

```
queries2.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <!-- Define un SQL Query nativo -->
    <sql-query name="test2">
        <![CDATA[
            SELECT 1+1 AS TEST1
        ]]>
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

this is my endpoint:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import jakarta.persistence.Query;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/users")
public class UsersController {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Object[]>> obtenerUsuarios() {
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("test");

        List<Object[]> result = query.getResultList();

        return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
    }
}
```

this is my JPAConfig:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(namedQueriesLocation = "classpath:/queries.xml")
public class JpaConfig {
}
```

i need to have two jpa repositories to use in my differents endpoints with my custom queries.

I have tried something like this but obviously is not working:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(namedQueriesLocation = "classpath:/queries.xml")
@EnableJpaRepositories(namedQueriesLocation = "classpath:/queries2.xml")
public class JpaConfig {
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Data JPA, you can only configure one `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation per configuration class, and it can specify only one location for named queries. However, you can achieve your goal of using multiple XML files for named queries by slightly modifying your setup.

Here's how you can do it:

1. Create a separate configuration class for each XML file containing named queries. You'll need a dedicated `@EnableJpaRepositories` configuration for each XML file.

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(namedQueriesLocation = "classpath:/queries.xml")
public class JpaConfig1 {
}
```

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(namedQueriesLocation = "classpath:/queries2.xml")
public class JpaConfig2 {
}
```

2. In your main application configuration class, include these additional configuration classes by using the `@Import` annotation:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Configuration
@Import({ JpaConfig1.class, JpaConfig2.class })
public class MainApplicationConfig {
}
```

Now, you have two separate configurations for named queries from `queries.xml` and `queries2.xml`. You can use these configurations in different parts of your application. When you define your repositories, make sure to specify the correct configuration class in the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation on your repository interface.

For example, if you have a repository interface `UserRepository`, you can specify which configuration to use like this:

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.repository", // Specify your repository package
                      entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryBeanName",
                      repositoryFactoryBeanClass = JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class,
                      repositoryBaseClass = SimpleJpaRepository.class,
                      namedQueriesLocation = "classpath:/queries.xml") // Choose the correct XML file
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    // Your repository methods here
}
```

Repeat this process for other repositories that need to use the queries from different XML files. This way, you can keep your named queries organized in separate XML files and use them as needed in your application.